# Unable to install a working copy of Bonobo git server

Tags: windows, installation, bonobo

I've installed the Bonobo server per the instructions here: https://bonobogitserver.com/install/

however, when I try to open the home page in edge I get a 404 error. In looking at the contents of the server's application directory I don't see a file the IIS server could use to crate the home page. Also the IIS manager contents does not look like the example figure in the "setting Anonymous Authentication" section. The forms and Interface directories are missing.

Have I missed something or is there another file I should be downloading I got the package from their home page (version 6.3.0)?

Comment: After moving from one server to the other, I have now same effect. Before, the same application worked with same content.